# Селектор вглубь iframe

Tags: jquery

Всем добрый день! Задача простейшая - выбрать элемент и кликнуть по нему. Но вот беда: элемент-то находится внутри `iframe`! Отсюда встает вопрос, как сделать выборку элемента по `id` с помощью `jQuery`? Стандартным способом `$("#someId")` возвращается `null`.
**Добавлено**:
фрейм не на моем домене(подгружается с вконтакте)

Comment: Фрейм на вашем домене?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Это не позволит браузер, политика безопасности. На plain js к фрейму со своего домена обращение такое:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.getElementById('myElement');
```

Но к элементу фрейма с другого домена так обратиться нельзя.

Теоретически можно подгружать вместо фрейма ajax'ом через curl-прокси (запрос вида "/myproxy.php?p=http://vkontakte.ru/..."), заменять в нем все ссылки на вашу прокси и после этого кликать. Но, хм, опять же, мне кажется, вконтакт это предусмотрел и даже такой грязный хак может не работать.

Comment: Вот засада :( Вопрос не актуален, спасибо за разъяснения!